# erro "bash: apidoc comand not found"

Tags: npm

olá instalei o apidoc pelo npm usando

```
npm install apidoc -g
npm install
```

em seguida:

```
-bash: apidoc -i . -o doc/
-bash: apidoc: comand not found
```

alguem sabe o motivo?

Comment: referencia api   http://apidocjs.com/

Comment: `which apidoc` retorna alguma coisa?

Comment: problema resolvido atualizando a versao do node